# Hover over image and have surrounding images darken

Tags: css, hover, opacity

For clarification: I'm not asking how to darken an image when you hover over it. I'm wondering how to make other images surrounding the image your cursor is over darken.

Here is an example: http://www.b-reel.com/

When you hover over the big category images, the surrounding images darken, but the hovered image remains the same.

Any input would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't make surrounding images darker. Instead, what you do is you put a `div` around all images, and when the cursor is over this `div`, all images are darker. But you also add `div` elements around each image, and you make an image less dark when the cursor is over it. The combination of both is what gives you the desired effect.

Comment: I'm a rookie at Jquery, so I decided to try your method first. I'm using background images instead of images for the sake of my design. I'm able to get all the images to darken on hover, but I'm having trouble making the single images remain at 100% opacity on hover. Here is a simplified version of my code:

edit: I'm such a novice at formatting these posts, I'm sorry!!

Comment: `<style>
#all {
 width: 600px; height: 200px;
 background: #000;
}
#all:hover {
 opacity: 0.5;
}
.square {
 float: left;
 width: 200px; height: 200px;
 background: url(img.jpg);
}
.square:hover {
 opacity: 1.0;
}
</style>


<div id="all">
 <div class="square"></div>
 <div class="square"></div>
 <div class="square"></div>
</div>`

Comment: Please add your code to the original message, this will make reading it a lot easier. In fact, putting it on jsFiddle would be even better.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. [Here's the jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/MRXtM/) As you can see, I'm struggling to get the individual squares to highlight.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you posted they are using JavaScript to apply a `.fadeOut` class on the other divs. That `.fadeOut` class sets the `opactiy` of the other divs to 50%.